# Failed to compile while addressing into css in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to set my images to css file but it gives errors that says failed to compile I am newbie in vue.

I tried @ for relative addressing from src

```
body{
  background: url("@/image/background.png");
}
```

But it erros me fail to compile anyway I tried another way and it show me error failed to compile again.

```
body{
  background: url("../image/background.jpg");
}
```

Whole error is:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../image/background.jpg' in '/home/sina/WebstormProjects/landing-vue/src'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 7:65-99
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"indentedSyntax":true,"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

my css file address :

```
src/assets/stylesheet/style.scss
```

my image file address :

```
src/assets/image/background.jpg
```

Comment: "It shows me an error" is not enough. Please paste in the error(s) you get.

Comment: @AKX whole error added to post

Comment: Well, are you sure the image does exist at that path with that name, upper/lowercase included?

Comment: @AKX yes i have and also webstorm underlines (red) the address that says cant resolve directory

Comment: @AKX so sorry how to fix that?

Comment: Is this code in `style.scss`  file or it's imported from another file to `style.scss`?

Comment: @ArminAyari it is in style.scss itself . alerts me first module not found before go to see errors. im stuck!

Comment: Try moving your stylesheet folder to src directory and out of assets folder

Comment: @ArminAyari nothing changed

Comment: @sinak did you change your url path after you moved your files?

Comment: @ArminAyari i just changed my scss to css and put address "../image/background.jpg"  and it is fixed . and the main problem is why @ doesnt work for me not only in scss file . doesnt detect @ at all project

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your image path actually be:

```
body{
  background: url("@/assets/image/background.jpg");
}
```

You stated your image path is `src/assets/image/background.jpg`.

`@` is an alias for `src/` but you still need to head into the `assets` folder.

I also changed `.png` to `.jpg`. Check your file extension too.

If the `@` alias doesn't work for you within `.scss` files, simply try linking relatively:

```
body{
  background: url("../image/background.jpg");
}
```

Obviously you would need to adjust the path according to where you have placed your stylesheets.

Comment: i pasted it incorrectly here accidentally . @ doesnt work at all!!